# Error when loading admin page of netlify cms

Tags: netlify, netlify-cms

Error when loading the admin page on the Netlify CMS.

config must have required property ‘media_folder’
config must have required property ‘media_library’
config must match a schema in anyOf

I have media_folder and I thought that media_library isn’t a required field, or am I wrong.

my config.yml file looks like this

`

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: main

media_folder: "public/images"
public_folder: "/images"

collections:
  - name: "event"
    label: "Event"
    folder: "src/event"
    create: true
    slug: "{{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}-{{slug}}"
    fields:
      - { label: "Event Title", name: "title", widget: "string" }
      - { label: "Event Type", name: "type", widget: "string" }
      - { label: "Event Description", name: "description", widget: "markdown" }
      - { label: "Event Date", name: "date", widget: "datetime" }
```

`
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is this your entire config file error message? Because this indeed looks correct... If not, do you mind sharing the entire thing?

Comment: yeah this is the entire error message @qbeauperin